# Python asyncio loop create_connection with dynamic port

Tags: python, sockets, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write a simple server with asyncio where I want to pass parameters to the protocol class and want the port to be allocated dynamically.
Using loop.create_connection lets me pass parameters to the protocol class:

```
coro = await loop.create_connection(lambda: MonitorProtocol(arg=arg),
                                    host=arg.host, port=40444)
```

But it doesn't let me choose a dynamic port whereas loop.create_server lets me choose a port dynamically but doesn't let me pass parameters to my protocol class.

```
coro = await loop.create_server(MonitorProtocol, host=arg.host, port=None)
```

Is there some way I can pass parameters to my protocol class and choose the port dynamically?

Comment: *But it doesn't let me choose a dynamic port* What do you mean by this? Surely the port doesn't have to be a constant?

Comment: With create_server, passing port=None automatically allocates a port number but this does not seem to work for create_connection

Comment: With `create_connection` you are specifying the port you are connecting **to**. That one cannot be dynamic AFAIK because it's on the remote side.